# WinCe - Implementing an Event Tracking Library

Tags: events, windows-ce, tracking

For Windows CE developers:

MS has scarce documentation on Implementing an Event Tracking Library.

I have registered an Event Tracking Library (as per the sample program in `%_WINCEROOT%\public\common\sdk\samples\CeLog\load`). However, when attempting to run `CeLogFlush.exe` on the custom event tracking dll, the CeLogFlush application complains that a CeLog map was not found.

Does anybody know if the custom Event Tracking Library is responsible for creating the `CELOG_DATAMAP_NAME (SYSTEM/CeLog Data)` or does the kernel do it?